# Views aggregation summary

Tags: views, css-js-aggregation

I am creating a stats page for a football (american) team in Drupal 7 and I am having issues summarizing the data.  I have the following fields aggregated in a views table. Each is a summary of the individual players for each game.

Game 1 , Passing Yards, Long Pass, Rushing Yards, Long Rush, etc

Game 2 , Passing Yards, Long Pass, Rushing Yards, Long Rush, etc

I want to print a summary line at the bottom that totals up the season.

I have tried the views_calc module, but I would rather print the summary as one line instead of a separate line for the sum and max fields.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Late but might be useful for someone, you can use [views_summarize](https://drupal.org/project/views_summarize) module.
Note: If you want to take export of your views using views_data_export module than views_summarize will create issues.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options that works for Drupal 7 and Drupal +8:

- https://www.drupal.org/project/views_summarize (create a summary, you can use the views default aggregation feature)
- https://www.drupal.org/project/views_aggregator (aggregate data without using DB function, witch open more feature. Also create a summary)